# socket.io and garbage collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have developed a realtime text web app using socket.io that continuously displays text on the web page. When I run my code below with multiple clients connecting the memory usage for the V8 javascript process on the server continues to grow and garbage collection doesn't appear to happen. Is it something with my code? Do I have a memory leak somewhere?

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
numOfUsers += 1;
var _RttPanes;

var sendText = function (input, callback) {
    var data = JSON.parse(input);
    socket.emit(data.action, input);
    callback();
};

socket.emit('RttConnect', 'connected');

socket.on('ReTryRttConnectRequest', function (strJsonMsg) {

    var payload = {
        jsonData: strJsonMsg,
        sendTranscriptToClient: sendText
    };

    //call ASP.NET code
    RetryRttPaneConnect(payload, true);
    //LogOff Kicked off User

    var clients = io.sockets.clients();
    var data = JSON.parse(strJsonMsg);
    for (i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
        if (clients[i].id == data.clientSocketID) {
            clients[i].emit("KickOff");
            break;
        }
    }
});
socket.on('RttConnectRequest', function (strJsonMsg) {

    //add socket id to json string
    var intPosition = strJsonMsg.indexOf("}");
    var strFirstPart = strJsonMsg.substring(0, intPosition);

    var strNewJson = strFirstPart + ',"socketID":"' + socket.id + '"}';

    var payload = {
        jsonData: strNewJson,
        sendTranscriptToClient: sendText
    };

    //call ASP.NET code
    RttPaneConnect(payload, true);
    //RttPaneConnect(payload, function (error, result) {
    //    if (error) throw error;
    //    console.log(result);
    //});

    //Add property to the socket
    var message = JSON.parse(strNewJson);
    socket.UserName = message.username.toLowerCase();

});

socket.on('RttReConnectRequest', function (strJsonMsg) {

    //add socket id to json string
    var intPosition = strJsonMsg.indexOf("}");
    var strFirstPart = strJsonMsg.substring(0, intPosition);

    var strNewJson = strFirstPart + ',"socketID":"' + socket.id + '"}';

    var payload = {
        jsonData: strNewJson,
        sendTranscriptToClient: sendText
    };

    //call ASP.NET code
    _RttPanes = RttPaneConnect(payload, true);
});

socket.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log("socket.io-client 'error'", err);
    //reconnect();
});

socket.on('connect_failed', function () {
    console.log("socket.io-client 'connect_failed'");
    //reconnect();
});

socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log("socket.io-client 'disconnect'");
    var strNewJson = '{"socketID":"' + socket.id + '"}';
    var payload = {
        jsonData: strNewJson,
        sendTranscriptToClient: sendText
    };
    //RttPaneDisconnect(payload, true);
    RttPaneDisconnect(payload, function (error) { console.log("socket.io-client 'disconnect EXIT'"); });

});

socket.on("LoggInUser", function (logInsocketid, logOffsocektid) {
    var clients = io.sockets.clients();
    for (i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
        if (clients[i].id == logInsocketid) {
            clients[i].emit("logOffCurrentUserSuccessful", logInsocketid, logOffsocektid);

            break;
        }
    }
});

socket.on('logOffCurrentUser', function (strJsonMsg) {

    var data = JSON.parse(strJsonMsg);
    var clients = io.sockets.clients();
    for(i=0;i<clients.length;i++){
        if (clients[i].UserName == data.username) {
            if(clients[i].id != socket.id){
                console.log("socket.io-client 'logOffCurrentUser' id: " + clients[i].id);

                var intPosition = strJsonMsg.indexOf("}");
                var strFirstPart = strJsonMsg.substring(0, intPosition);

                //add socket id to json string
                var strNewJson = strFirstPart + ',"socketID":"' + socket.id + '" , "clientSocketID":"' + clients[i].id + '"}';

                var payload = {
                    jsonData: strNewJson,
                    sendTranscriptToClient: sendText
                };

                //disconnect user Global Server
                RttPaneDisconnectFirstAndConnectSecond(payload, function (error, result) {
                    if (error) {
                        console.log('Ahh! An Error!');
                        return;
                    }
                    console.log("forceLogOff socket.id, clients[i].id: " + socket.id + "   " + clients[i].id);
                    clients[i].emit("forceLogOff", socket.id, clients[i].id);
                });
                break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Profiling your code is the only definitive way you can know. You can use [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) to profile your code.

Comment: This question sounds more like it belongs on stack overflow.  You have a problem with your code that you want help with.

Comment: @jfriend00 err... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36872162/socket-io-and-garbage-collection

Comment: You say your code is not functioning properly (leaking memory) and thus has some sort of bug.  code review is for code that is functioning properly already.